# Consume RESTFul services from a JavaFX application

Tags: rest, javafx-2

I am trying to understand what would be the best way approach to consume RESTFul services deployed on Websphere from a JavaFX application. A few options I know of are:

1. Jersey
2. RESTEasy
3. Spring3

I am not sure how they fit in given the consumption from the JavaFX application. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

*API Choice*

Any of the above will work fine.

There is nothing really JavaFX specific about this.

You can google the web for a comparison of your candidate client rest client apis, or just download one of them and start using it.

---

*Implementation Pointers*

All you need to do is to include the jars for your chosen rest client framework with your application and then code to the documented api for your rest client and the restful service you are consuming.

You may want to consider the [DataFX library](http://www.javafxdata.org/) as a way to get data retrieved from the rest apis into your JavaFX controls.

Most of the libraries you listed are hosted in a public maven repository, so you could use a [JavaFX maven plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) to bundle them with your app.  Building using the standard [JavaFX deployment tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb//docs/java/javafx-setup.html) will work fine too.

You'll want to make your rest calls on a background thread, so review the [JavaFX concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) resources to see how this is done.

Unless you need a platform independent data transfer format and protocol or you are consuming existing rest services, it may be simpler to use a remote method or object invoking protocol to communicate with the server (e.g. [spring remoting](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/02/25/going-remote-javafx-and-spring-remoting/) or [hessian](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/03/client-server-with-javafx-2-and-hessian-guice-fxml/)).  Such protocols usually handle transfer error conditions and automatation of marshaling and unmarshaling of java objects to a transfer format.  With a rest API, you generally need to implement such features yourself.

---

*Sample Code*

Take a look at the [Henley Sales Sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) which includes client and server components for generating and consuming rest apis and for utilizing the resultant data in a JavaFX UI.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea for the wonderfully explained response. I tried Jersey, but could not proceed as the parser failed to work(or maybe I missed something) for custom datatypes. It worked pretty well with 

primitive datatypes. I used the code below to parse the JSON to map it to my objects:

`code` List<Color> colors = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Color>>()
             {
             });

Comment: My Color.java is below:

`code` public class Color
{

    public String  colorCode;
    public String  colorDescription;
    public Boolean activeFlag;

    public ColorDTO(String colorCode, String colorDescription, Boolean activeFlag)
    {
        super();
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
        this.colorDescription = colorDescription;
        this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
    }

Comment: After this the setters and getters

Comment: Better to update the question with what you tried than put the code in comments.

Comment: The exception I get is below:

`code` com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<com.model.Aisle>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:535)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:696)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:196)
 at com.webservice.RestProvider.main(RestProvider.java:48)

Comment: Or perhaps better yet, for this instance, create a new question which is specific to the issue at hand.

Comment: I did try to use spring's resttemplate, but that also had to abandon midway. Exception is below: `code` Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBe